# Can't pass \ in option to package processed with xkeyval - TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: package-options, xkeyval

I have a test package that uses the xkeyval package to process options.  The package works when I pass an option value that does not have \ in it but when I pass yy=\tiny I get

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@nomath ...e \@font@warning {Command \noexpand #1
                                                  invalid in math mode}\fi 
l.3 \begin
          {document}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

My test .tex and .sty files are below.

```
% testpkg.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[yy=\tiny]{testpkg}
\begin{document}
yy: \yy this and that
\end{document}

% testpkg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpkg}[2015/10/28 Test package]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\newif\ifloadjunk
\DeclareOptionX{loadjunk}{\loadjunktrue}
\DeclareOptionX{yy}{\def\yy{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{yy=3}    % set default value for yy option
\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\ifloadjunk
\RequirePackage{junk}
\fi
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. It has nothing to do with the `\ `. It is just because it is a font command.

Comment: How does one properly pass a font command as an option using xkeyval?

Comment: Options passed to `\usepackage` are subject to full expansion. It's a known limitation of the option loading mechanism, and it implies that macros are not usually welcome there.

Comment: The documentation says in 12.2 xkvltxp a bit about commands in options. I would avoid to overload the options system with complicated stuff, it leads to "option clash" problems and interferences with the document options. Better define a `\textpkgsetup` command which is called after the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpkg}[2015/10/28 Test package]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\newcommand*\yy{\relax}
\DeclareOptionX{yy}{%
  \renewcommand*\yy{\csname#1\endcsname}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{yy=normalsize}    % set default value for yy option
\ProcessOptionsX\relax
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[yy=tiny]{\jobname}
\begin{document}
yy: \yy this and that
\end{document}
```

Note that it is better to use `\newcommand` and friends than `\def` and companions except where only the latter will work.

Comment: That worked.  It is too bad you have to pass [tiny] instead of [\tiny] (just for consistency with regular LaTeX).  I'd be interested in knowing the downside of \def.

Comment: What's `\expandafter` supposed to do? When `yy=tiny` is used, the replacement text of `\yy` becomes `\expandafter\csname tiny\endcsname`, and you see that you're trying to expand a `t`.

Comment: @egreg No idea.

Comment: @FrankHarrell `\def` will happily overwrite an existing command. It performs no checking. `\newcommand` checks that the command name is new and complains if not. It is safer to use `\newcommand` in LaTeX documents. (Or commands from something like `xparse` which extend the syntax for creating new macros.)